# BootstrapDatePicker displaying by default date day and timezone

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I need only the date (mm/dd/yy) when I select date from `BootstrapDatePicker`.

But it's displaying whole day, date, time e.g.

`Tue May 31 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)`

Comment: Could you post some code? What technologies are you using, just straight HTML or is there more to it? [Asking good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Modify options:

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
});
```

https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html

Comment: Ya  modified options.Even then it's showing the same way

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what's wrong with my old code.It's displaying whole day, date, time e.g. Tue May 31 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time) in my old one.

old code:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.datepicker = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        var options = allBindingsAccessor().dateTimePickerOptions || { locale: 'da', format: 'DD-MM-YYYY' };
        $(element).datetimepicker(options);
        var options = allBindingsAccessor().datepickerOptions || {

                 autoclose: true,
                 format: 'mm/dd/yy',
                 orientation: 'bottom auto',


        };

        $(element).datepicker(options).on("changeDate", function (ev) {
            var observable = valueAccessor();
            observable(ev.date);
        });
    },

    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        $(element).datepicker("setValue", value);
        $(element).datepicker("hide");
    }



};
```

My new code:

```
   ko.bindingHandlers.datepicker = 
{
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings) {
        //initialize datepicker with some optional options
        var options = allBindings.get('datepickerOptions') ||
            {
                autoclose: true,
                orientation: 'bottom auto',
                format: 'mm-dd-yyyy'
        };
        $(element).datepicker(options);

        //when a user changes the date, update the view model
        ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "changeDate", function (event) {
            var value = valueAccessor();
            if (ko.isObservable(value)) {
                value(event.date);
            }
        });

        //disposal logic
        ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function () {
            $(element).datepicker("remove");
        });
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        $(element).datepicker('update', value);
    }
};
```

My new code worked :)
Thanks for your suggestions.